# setup or maintain SSO on particular salesforce app

Tags: single-sign-on

Any idea on how to setup of maintain the single sign on particular salesforce app. For example on click of the link of the app the user no longer need to enter the credentials.

Thanks.

Comment: We're going to need more details than this. There's a few ways to set up SSO, including SAML login, Canvas Apps, Connected Apps, etc. It really depends on what you plan on doing.

Comment: For example the is one app with link that is directed to another app. Once I click that link it should maintain the SSO.